# Submit form with multiple conditions not working

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement

**Situation**

I have a submit form. With this form, users are able to reserve a table in a restaurant. With each submit there is some data send to the database with the `wp_insert_post` function. For example the `user_ip` and the `datum_nieuwe_reservering`(explained later). I want to use this to check if the user is allowed to submit a new reservation(prevent spamming). I have tried a couple of thing, but it's not working. See code below.

**Question**

How can I get this to work? What am I doing wrong?

**CODE**
*reserving.php*

```
<!-- CODE WHEN POST = SUBMIT, MAKE A NEW RESERVATION.
=========================================== -->
<?php
global $wpdb;
$user_ip_db = getUserIP();
$date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

//echo $date;

$check_user_ip = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_ip_reservering' AND meta_value = '$user_ip_db'");
$check_time_new = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'datum_nieuwe_reservering'");

print_r($check_time_new);


if ( isset($_POST['submit_reservering']) ) {
  if ( (empty($check_user_ip)) && $date > $check_time_new ) {
      create_reservering();
      echo "Your reservation has been send";
    } else {
    echo 'You have already reserved';
  }
}

?><!-- end CODE FOR MAKING RESERVATION-->
```

*Plugin file*

```
//Using this function to send the current day + 1 day to the database
//with a hidden text field named `datum_nieuwe_reservering`(show below)
//and in the end check if current date >= `datum_nieuwe_reservering`
<?php
 function getDateTime(){
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
 $next_day = time() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
 $date_now = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
 $date_tomorrow = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $next_day);

 echo $date_tomorrow;
}
?>
```

*Hidden field for `datum_nieuwe_reservering`*

```
 <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo getDateTime(); ?>' name='datum_nieuwe_reservering'>
```

NOTE: The submit form is working correctly with the `if (empty($check_user_ip)) { };` code only. So I'm struggle to add the date in the if statement too.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction!
 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use brackets in condition?

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit_reservering']) ) {
  if  ( (empty($check_user_ip)) && ($date > $check_time_new) ) {
      create_reservering();
      echo "Your reservation has been send";
    } else {
    echo 'You have already reserved';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, already tried but not working either unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_reservering']) === true) {
    $reserved = false;
    if (empty($check_user_ip) === true) {
        $test = end($check_time_new);
        if(date > $test->meta_value) {
            create_reservering();
            echo "Your reservation has been send";
        } else {
            echo 'You have already reserved';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share what "print_r($check_time_new);" returns?

Comment: Well you can't just compare an array with stdClass Objects with a timestamp. First you should check if you really just get the data of the user itself. Then you could foreach the stdClass Object Array and check if there is at least one record with date > check_new_time. When this occurs you can say "reserve"

Comment: You have multiple dates in your Array. Are they all by the same user?

Comment: The updated answer should work. I dont have much knowledge about stdObjects so you should try either $test->meta_value and $test['meta_value']. If this piece doesn't work try it with $date = time() strtotime($test) -> if($date > strtotime($test->meta_value))

Comment: I updated my answer again. It will now just take the last entry of your check_new_time...Just try it with another record where the date of end($check_time_now) is before now (where the meta_value is smaller than 28-03-2017 16:08:23). It should work properly then.

Comment: To test it you just can set $date = "29-03-2017 12:12:12";